# How can I run a startup script for GNURoot Debian?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, linux, shell, ssh

I've installed GNURoot debian on a rooted Android device and I can launch a debian shell programmatically using `am`, but I couldn't figure out how to run a command like starting dropbear.

What's the recommended way of running a command straight after launching and GNURoot Debian shell ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write a simple start script and save it in `/system/init.d/` given that the kernel supports this (most do) and you have write permission on `/system`

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a go, so far I've tried the ```/etc/init.d``` route and didn't get very far

Comment: Can you edit or comment how to _"launch a debian shell programmatically using `am`"_ for educative purposes?

Comment: @Redsandro I wouldn't mind changing the title if it makes clearer.
I've already launched  what I needed via `am`, my question is about launching an SSH Daemon in the background within GNURoot Debian as an init.d/startup script

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I know you already launched it. I don't have an answer. But your question comes up when I google _"how do I launch a debian shell programmatically."_ If you would be so kind and add the specific commands  for that knowledge you already posess to the question, people like me will be educated from reading your question, even though we cannot answer _your_ question. :)

Comment: @Redsandro Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but there is little I can do to control the results of search engines :) My question isn't about launching a shell programmatically. I am confused

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Forgive me for not wording this better. English is not my native language. If you replace the words _"using `am`"_ with the words _"by entering the following commands: [insert commands]"_, then __your question__ would __answer mine__ (and others who come here with the same question (my question, not yours) from google).

Answer (score 0):

To install:
`apt install dropbear`

To start:
`service start dropbear`

Autostart:
Make sure `enable` is set to `1` in `/etc/config/dropbear`.